# Listview item image and textview reloading in multiple position in Realmbaseadapter

Tags: android, listview, realm

According to my app requirement I am showing a row with textbox,imageview and image capture button in a listview. I am capturing an image and immediately saving that image in that realm row. Then adapter loads that image from related realm object when adaoter getview method gets called.

My problem is when the row data for each list is blank, has more than 4 rows and capturing any image; captured image gets loaded in several position along with the position it is meant to be. 
For example if I take image for position 0 it shows after scrolling in position 5,then again reloads to position 6. I have noticed that since after scrolling from position 0 to position 6 adapter position returns 0 again. Which is the reason of the image reloading during scrolling in other positions. When I click in any button for either taking picture/text input this reloaded row again returns to proper position.

I went through almost all possible suggested SO questions related to issue imageview shuffling in listview but none of them works for me.Could you suggest any solution to this problem.
My Adapter code is below-

```
 public class ProgressImageAdapter extends RealmBaseAdapter<ImageCommentRealm> implements ListAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    String categoryName;
    ProgressListener progressListener;
    PopAlertDialog alertDialog;
    boolean fromHistory;

    public ProgressImageAdapter(Context context, OrderedRealmCollection<ImageCommentRealm> data, ProgressListener progressListener, boolean fromHistory) {
        super(context, data);
        this.mContext = context;
        this.progressListener = progressListener;
        FragmentActivity activity = (FragmentActivity) (context);
        alertDialog = PopAlertDialog.createAlert(activity.getSupportFragmentManager());
        this.fromHistory = fromHistory;
    }

    @Override
    public void updateData(OrderedRealmCollection<ImageCommentRealm> data) {
        super.updateData(data);
    }

    public void resetListener() {
        this.progressListener = null;
    }

    public void setCategoryName(String categoryName) {
        this.categoryName = categoryName;
    }

    @Override
    public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
        super.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_comment_list_item, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
            holder.editText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.et_comment);
            holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_camera_holder);
            holder.imageButton = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgbtn_camera);
            holder.btnDone = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_confirm);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        final ImageCommentRealm imageCommentRealm = getItem(position);
        holder.textView.setText(String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%s %d %2s %2s", mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.photo), position + 1, mContext.getString(R.string.of), categoryName));
        if (Validator.blankCheck(imageCommentRealm.getFile_path()))
            loadImage(holder.imageView, imageCommentRealm.getFile_path());
        if (Validator.blankCheck(imageCommentRealm.getDesc()))
            holder.editText.setText(imageCommentRealm.getDesc());
        if (!fromHistory) {
            holder.imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    ((MainActivity) mContext).pickFromCamera();
                    ((MainActivity) mContext).setPicker(new IPhotoPicker() {
                        @Override
                        public void setImageUri(String filePath) {
                            //loadImage(holder,filePath);
                            saveData(null, filePath, imageCommentRealm.getPk());

                        }
                    });
                }
            });
            holder.editText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    String title = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%s %d %2s %2s", mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.description), position + 1, mContext.getString(R.string.of), categoryName);
                    alertDialog.showSingleInput(title, imageCommentRealm.getDesc(), imageCommentRealm.getPk(), new SingleInput.Listener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClickGreen(String message, long id) {
                            if (Validator.blankCheck(message)) saveData(message, null, id);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
        return convertView;
    }

    protected void loadImage(ImageView imageView, String imgPath) {
        if (imgPath.startsWith("http")) {
            ImageUtility.loadProduct(mContext, imgPath, imageView, R.drawable.home);
        } else {
            try {
                File image_file = new File(imgPath);
                if (image_file.exists()) {
                    Bitmap image_profile = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image_file.getAbsolutePath());
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(image_profile);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }


    private void saveData(final String comment, final String filepath, final long pk) {
        final Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(RealmUtility.getRealmConfig(mContext));
        //ImageCommentRealm imageRealm = getItem(position);
        //final long pk = imageRealm.getPk();
        realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm realm) {
                ImageCommentRealm imageCommentRealm = realm.where(ImageCommentRealm.class).equalTo("pk", pk).findFirst();
                if (imageCommentRealm != null && imageCommentRealm.isLoaded()) {
                    if (Validator.blankCheck(comment)) {
                        imageCommentRealm.setDesc(comment);
                    }
                    if (Validator.blankCheck(filepath)) {
                        imageCommentRealm.setFile_path(filepath);
                    }
                }

            }
        }, new Realm.Transaction.OnSuccess() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {

                //notifyDataSetChanged();
                realm.close();
                try {
                    if (adapterData != null && adapterData.size() > 0) {
                        long count = adapterData.where().isNotNull("file_path").isNotNull("desc").count();
                        if (count == adapterData.size()) {
                            if (progressListener != null) progressListener.hasRequiredImage();
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Realm.Transaction.OnError() {
            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
                realm.close();
            }
        });
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView textView;
        TextView editText;
        ImageView imageView;
        ImageButton imageButton;
        Button btnDone;
    }
}
```

Here is a screenshot after taking picture in first position and then scrolling to bottom 
[image]

FYI: Testing device 4" Samsung J1 Nxt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eh, this has nothing to do with Realm, you should clear the image if the image path is null.

```
    if (Validator.blankCheck(imageCommentRealm.getFile_path())) {
        loadImage(holder.imageView, imageCommentRealm.getFile_path());
    } else {
        holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(null);
    }
    if (Validator.blankCheck(imageCommentRealm.getDesc()))
        holder.editText.setText(imageCommentRealm.getDesc());
    } else {
        holder.editText.setText("");
    }
```